# The sign of a continuous function around one of its zeros

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Let $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, where $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ is some interval. Suppose there is some $a\in I$ such that $f(a)=0$. I want to know what we can say about $f$'s sign around this point $a$.

Intuitively, one of the two following situations must occur:
$\bullet$ $f\ge 0$ or $f\le 0$ in a neighborhood of $a$
$\bullet$ in every neighborhood of $a$ there is some $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x)>0$ and $f(y)<0$.

I think that these are the only possibilities, but I reached these conclusions by doodling on a scratch paper. How should I go about proving them rigorously?

Furthermore, I suspect that continuity is essential here. Could someone provide a counterexample to my claim, i.e. a discontinuous function for which it is not necessary that my bullet points oocur?

Comment: If you formally negate condition 1, you get condition 2.  That seems pretty rigorous to me.  Continuity has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Have you considered $f(x)= x^2$?  It is 0 at x= 0 but is positive on both sides of x= 0.

Comment: @user247327 well this is covered by the first bullet point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one of those situations must occur, but this is true even if $f$ is discontinuous at $a$. In fact, suppose that the first condition dos *not* hold, that is, suppose that it is not true that there is some neighborhood $U$ of $a$ such that you have$$(\forall x\in U):f(x)\geqslant0\quad\text{or}\quad(\forall x\in U):f(x)\leqslant0.\tag1$$Then, for *every* neighborhood $U$ of $a$ you *don't* have $(1)$, which is the same thing as asserting that there is some $x\in U$ such that $f(x)<0$ and that there is some $y\in U$ such that $f(y)>0$.

Comment: Carlos Santos ah, right, thank you very much! I also suspected at some point that continuity has nothing to do with it, but I supsected that there are some ugly counterexamples I am missing. It makes sense now, thank you!